# How to find Nephew in Prolog Family Code?

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to get Prolog to output people in the family trees nephew, as in `nephew(X,Y)` will list

```
X = the nephew
Y = Aunt/ Uncle
```

I've tried writing some of the code already, I'm pretty confident the son command works, and I believe sibling works, however combining these is proving, difficult.

```
parent(pam,bob).
parent(john,bob).
parent(john,liz).
parent(bob,ann).
parent(bob,pat).
parent(pat,jim).
parent(liz,joe).
parent(liz,tim).
parent(joe,kim).

female(pam).
female(liz).
female(ann).
female(pat).
female(zoe).
female(kim).

male(bob).
male(john).
male(jim).
male(joe).
male(tim).

sibling(X, Y) :- parent(Z, X), parent(Z, Y), X \= Y.

son(X,Y) :- parent(Y, X), male(X).

nephew(X, Y) :- sibling(Y, Z), son(Z, X).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were so close.

If you ran your query

`nephew(X,Y)` you would get

```
?- nephew(X,Y).
X = pam,
Y = liz ;
X = john,
Y = liz ;
X = liz,
Y = joe ;
X = liz,
Y = tim ;
false.
```

which as you note is wrong.

However if you rename your variables so that they are easier to comprehend

```
sibling(Child_a, Child_b) :-
    parent(Parent, Child_a),
    parent(Parent, Child_b),
    Child_a \= Child_b.

son(Child,Parent) :-
    parent(Parent, Child),
    male(Child).

nephew(Parent, Child_a) :-
    sibling(Child_a, Child_b),
    son(Child_b, Parent).
```

you will see that sibling/2 and son/2 are correct and should see your problem with nephew/2.

When renaming variables, start at the facts and work back, do not start at the head of a clause and work down.

---

Another way that helps to figure out problems with multi-statement predicates is to run parts of them as separate queries, e.g.

```
?- sibling(Parent,Aunt_uncle),son(Nephew,Parent).
Parent = liz,
Aunt_uncle = bob,
Nephew = joe ;
Parent = liz,
Aunt_uncle = bob,
Nephew = tim ;
Parent = pat,
Aunt_uncle = ann,
Nephew = jim ;
false.
```

While this query gives more information than is needed, the correct values are in the results. Putting this in a predicate and returning only the desired values is all that is left to get this query working as desired.

---

A correct answer for nephew/2 is

```
nephew(Nephew,Aunt_uncle) :-
    sibling(Parent,Aunt_uncle),
    son(Nephew,Parent).
```

Example run:

```
?- nephew(Nephew,Aunt_uncle).
Nephew = jim,
Aunt_uncle = ann ;
Nephew = joe,
Aunt_uncle = bob ;
Nephew = tim,
Aunt_uncle = bob ;
false.
```

---

When writing code it is advisable to also create test cases.

If you are using SWI-Prolog then you can use the following test cases.

```
:- begin_tests(family).

% example of single test case

test(001) :-
    sibling(bob,liz).

test(002) :-
    son(tim,liz).

test(003,[nondet]) :-
    nephew(tim,bob).

% example of test cases that test multiple variations for one predicate

sibling_test_case(bob,liz).
sibling_test_case(liz,bob).
sibling_test_case(ann,pat).
sibling_test_case(pat,ann).
sibling_test_case(joe,tim).
sibling_test_case(tim,joe).

test(004, [forall(sibling_test_case(Child_a,Child_b))]) :-
    sibling(Child_a,Child_b).

son_test_case(bob,pam).
son_test_case(bob,john).
son_test_case(jim,pat).
son_test_case(joe,liz).
son_test_case(tim,liz).

test(005, [forall(son_test_case(Child,Parent)),nondet]) :-
    son(Child,Parent).

nephew_test_case(joe,bob).
nephew_test_case(tim,bob).
nephew_test_case(jim,ann).

test(006, [forall(nephew_test_case(Nephew,Aunt_uncle)),nondet]) :-
    nephew(Nephew,Aunt_uncle).

:- end_tests(family).
```

These are run with `run_tests.`

```
?- run_tests.
% PL-Unit: family ................. done
% All 17 tests passed
true.
```

See: [Prolog Unit Tests](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section(%27packages/plunit.html%27))